# Runtime error by `babel/runtime-corejs3` importing `core-js-pure`

Tags: babeljs, node-modules, babel-loader, adyen

I have an issue related to the package `@babel/runtime-corejs3` importing `core-js-pure` in my Vue application.

My browser console throws the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/Users/xxx/Documents/projects/xxx/node_modules/core-js-pure/features/promise/index.js?v=570da9ba' does not provide an export named 'default' (at asyncToGenerator.js:1:8)`

This is caused by the following line of code in `node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js`:

`import _Promise from "/@fs/Users/a.akbulut/Documents/projects/embeddables/node_modules/core-js-pure/features/promise/index.js?v=76e5cea3";`

The issue is that there is no default export for `_Promise`, as the file contains the following:
`'use strict'; module.exports = require('../../full/promise');`

I confirmed `@adyen/adyen-web` is the only package in my application that uses `@babel/runtime-corejs3` & `core-js-pure`.

I noticed there has been a new tag release 3 days ago: [5.61.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adyen/adyen-web/v/5.61.0).

However I tried to install  `"@adyen/adyen-web": "5.60.0"` but it did not solve the issue.

Some extra info:

- Node version 21.7.1
- NPM version 10.5.0

Help is appreciated.